# Optimum memory usage in R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, memory, amazon-ec2

I have been using 64 bit Windows machine. The RStudio as well as R is also 64 bit. I am using these on an EC2 instance which is r5.4xlarge. It has 16 core and about 128G memory. If I run command `memory.limit()` I see 100GB. Since , in the .RProfile file I have set this memory limit. Still when I use the RScript I see only 10GB memory being in use in Task Manager.

How should I make sure R uses optimum memory so that the script is run much more faster? If I run same script on my local with 64 GB RAM the script finishes in 5 minutes with 100% CPU usage but on EC2 it finishes in 15 minutes with only 25% CPU usage. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: It's not clear to me that RAM is responsible for the performance difference you see between the 2 computers. Could you please provide the session information for both machines, as well as a simple benchmark script that you run on both machines with the output from the benchmarks for both?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that memory is the issue on this.

Since you note that the server only runs with 25% of CPU usage and 100% locally, it could that your code is parallelized locally and an not on the VM.

Another thing to look at is are you running Microsoft R Open locally? and not on the VM?
R Open uses the Intel MKL (Math Kernel  library) by default. which is a much faster implementation of the BLAS libraries.

```
sessionInfo()
```

for the standard R library

```
other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-12
```

and for R Open (something like )

```
other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0
```

Comment: For the Local and server I have Matrix_1.2-14 under loaded via a namespace (and not attached): For Server I have-           R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200) For Local I have - R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200) For Local I just have more packages loaded like -attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base

Comment: Hard to tell with out looking at what the code is doing . Since 100% of CPU is used locally it could mean that R is running multithreaded locally , load parallel on the server.

Comment: The code is as below-d_train_attom1 <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(PLE_attom1_train_v3[,-c(1:14)]),label =PLE_attom1_train_v3$event)
params <- list( booster = "gbtree",objective = "binary:logistic", eta=0.3,gamma=5, max_depth=3,  min_child_weight=1, subsample = 1, 
                colsample_bytree = 1,eval_metric = "error",nthread=16,
                early_stop_round =10 )
time1 = Sys.time()
xgbcv_hqdata1 <- xgb.cv( params = params, data = d_train_attom1, nrounds = 200,nfold = 5, showsd = T, stratified = T, print_every_n = 10,
                         maximize = T )
Sys.time() -time1

Comment: Looks like xgboost is not running on multiple threads. You can change the nthread parameter = -1 (default) to use all available threads, if this does not make a difference, then the xgboost installed does not have threading enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried -1 option even before trying 16 but it did not help. How to make sure xgboost install to have threading enabled? Interesting thing is when I do nthread=1 then script runs even more slow. Hence, I had assumed that nthread is working.

Comment: What does parallel::detectCores(logical=TRUE) return?

Comment: I ended up creating new EC2 instance this time unix. Downloaded RStudio. It is r5.24xlarge instance. I see following-                  > parallel::detectCores(logical=TRUE)
[1] 96

Comment: Here are the numbers on unix-                          
m4.4xlarge 14 minutes
r5.24xlarge 12 minutes. data scientist has reported 5 minutes for the same code on local with 64GB RAM. EC2 so much larger resources but performance is lower. Something is not adding up.

Comment: was xgboost installed from precompiled binaries or was it compiled during install?

Comment: It was just installed by using RStudio -> Tools -> install package -> xgboost.

Comment: This issue was finally solved when we used xgboost_0.6.4.1 version and R version 3.3.0. We can great performance when we used high end servers (More RAM and more Cores).